# How do I check if a base class implementation is called?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm having a piece of code like this:

```cs
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract void foo();
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void foo()
    {
        // Do something, but obviously don't call base.foo();
    }
}

// ... we have many implementations of A, and hence many implementations of foo, too.
```

Now I found that `A.foo()` should no longer be abstract, as I need it to update some status. Is there an easy way to find all the (missing) `base.foo()` calls in my code base? Obviously I can search for it, but is there a safer way? VS shows `76 references` on the implementation of `A.foo()`, even though I haven't added a single real call to it.

Comment: If the new behavior is unconditional for correct behavior, consider instead making clients call `realFoo()`, and `realFoo()` implemented as `foo(); // update some status`, so derived classes do not have to rely on calling `base.foo` to begin with. `foo` can then be made `protected`. These are still breaking changes, but they can be applied mechanically, as changing a method's name and visibility breaks code in obvious ways.

Comment: check if you can use code analysis tools

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm aware of this approach,  but I'd like to not change the API. I would prefer to have a list that tell me which overloads call the base and which don't.